# Return value from JAVA API Value

Tags: java, ajax, api, return

On the click of a button I am sending a JSON to the Java Server side via an API POST call.On validating the JSON, the server side function return a String.

How do I access that string on my JavaScript client side?
That String will tell me whether the JSON is valid or not.

Comment: use jquery ajax POST, implement the success handler block

Comment: What do you mean that the server side function returns a String? How does it do so? Where does it return to?

Comment: Please show how you send the POST request. I bet that your `success` function from that already returns your response. Read the documentation for that post function

Comment: function xhrPostCall(jsonInput, postUrl){
  xhrPost.open("POST",postUrl, true);
  xhrPost.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 xhrPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhrPost.readyState == 4 && xhrPost.status == 200) {
     msg="Environment Succesfully Added!";
     alert(xhrPost.status+jsonInput+msg);
          console.log('posting succesful:'+jsonInput+msg);
      }   else{msg="Environment Unsuccessfully Added!";
    alert(xhrPost.status+jsonInput+msg);
    console.log('posting unsuccessful'+jsonInput+msg);
   }
  }
  xhrPost.send(jsonInput);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use **parseJSON(json)** function in jQuery, for example:

```
          function getValue(actionName) {   
              $j.ajax({
                 url: actionName + ".do",
                 data: {
                    "action" : "getJsonValue"
                  },
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(response) {
                     if (response.errorCode) {
                         showErrorMessage(response.errorMessage);
                         return;
                     }
                     response = $j.parseJSON(response);
                     return response;
                  },
               });
           }
```